# Testing if shell variable is set

Tags: bash

I am doing

```
local w=""
if [[ -v "$w" ]]; then
  echo
  printf '%s\n' "VARIABLE SET TEST"
  printf '%s\n' "  w=\"$w\" | w: $w"
  printf '%s\n'  \
    "  [[ -v \"\$w\" ]] TRUE, w is not set to a value by assignment"
  printf '%s\n'  \
    "  [[ ! -v \"\$w\" ]] FALSE, w is not set to a value by assignment"
fi
```

`[[ -v "$w" ]]` should return True if the shell variable is set (has been assigned a value).  But this is returning false.

Comment: You should test the variable's *name*, `-v varname` not its *value* `-v "$varname"` I think?

Comment: So it is not the expansion of `$varname` that I want.

Comment: Simpler: `if test "${w+x}"` (or equivalently `if [ "${w+x}" ]`).  Cutely, `if ${w+true} false`

Comment: @TobySpeight, or confusingly, `if [ "${w+false}" ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `[[ -v var ]]` takes the variable *name*, not the expanded value. With just the value, it wouldn't be able to tell the difference between an unset variable and a variable set to the empty string.

So,

- `[[ -v var ]]` tests if `var` is set (but it can be empty)
- `[[ -n "$var" ]]` tests if `var` expands to a non-empty string, i.e. is set and not empty
- `[[ "$var" ]]` same as above
- `[[ -z "$var" ]]` tests if `var` expands to an empty string, i.e. is unset or set to the empty string.

Though note that the latter two will croak if the variable is unset and `set -u` is in effect. You'd need to use e.g. the default value expansion `"${var-default}"` to avoid that. Also the `-v` test is not standard, look into
[DaG's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745339/170373) for a method that should work in all POSIX-like shells.

Answer (score 2):

To determine if variable is set

`-z` returns 0 (true) if length of string is zero.

`${var+x}` if variable (var) is set, expands to `x`

```bash
[ -z "${var+x}" ] && echo "variable unset"
```

`-n` returns 0 (true) if length of string is non-zero

```bash
[ -n "${var+x}" ] && echo "variable set"
```

To check variable and display error when unset use:

```bash
"${var?warn_unset}"
```

To check if variables are unset or **empty** use `:` before `+`/`?` character.

```bash
[ -z "${var:+x}" ] && echo "variable unset or empty"
```

```bash
"${var:?warn_unset_or_empty}"
```

Comment: With `${var:+x}`, you get `x` only if the variable is set and non-empty. Without the colon `${var+x}`, you get `x` is it's set to any value. Same with `${var:?error}`, it'd also trigger for a set but empty value, not just an unset one.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, oh, I guess my comment above is for you.

Comment: @ilkkachu oh, that's true! my bad. I really thought they missed the colons, I had no idea about that until I tried what you said. Thanks!

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, yep, one often sees just the ones with the colon. Sadly, [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), hides the distinction within the text, it says _"Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. [...] if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence."_ but all the examples are with the colon. The [POSIX text has a nice table of all the variants](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), though, so at least here, it's a better read.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question. I thought that you want to test **if variable is set** not if it's empty...

Comment: @ilkkachu And I just realized that the relevant text is above the examples haha :). Also, thanks for the link, it's more useful and handy!